# Add Where condition to child collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two models `Invoice` and `StockItems` where `StockItems` is the child model. I would like to get the invoices with their `StockItems` where `StockItem.Used` is True.

This is the query I used:

```
var Invoices = _dbcontext.Invoice
                         .Include(a => a.StockItems)
                         .Where(s => s.StockItems.Any(a => a.Used == true))
                         .ToList();
```

But the `Where` condition doesn't get applied, the query returns all the `StockItems` whatever the value of `StockItem.Used` property True and False.

So where is the error in my query?

Comment: Your initial query applies the `Where` condition to Invoices and says only include invoices that have `Any` `StockItems` that are `Used` - so it is being applied and working correctly. It just isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the query:

```
var Invoices = _dbcontext.Invoice
                     .Include(a => a.StockItems.Where(s => s.Used == true))
                     .ToList();
```